# On iOS10 userNotification didn't show in Banners with no errors, it only worked when iPhone was locked

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I set for 3 second to notify me the message, but I wait for 30 even more seconds with nothing happen to Banners. However, if I lock the iPhone, it will be a message appear on time on the lock screen. I try for several times and they all come to this result. I am confused with it for 3 days, wishing somebody helping me solve this problem. Many thanks for your advices!
That's all code related to userNotifications

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Tomorrow night"
    content.subtitle = "Old place"
    content.body = "A meal"
    content.badge = 1

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false)
    //let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)

    let requestIdentifier = "com.cheio.Stundenplan"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if error == nil {
            print("Time Interval Notification scheduled: \(requestIdentifier)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Local notifications are not shown when your app is the currently active app.

Comment: Thanks for your pointing, I am totally benighted.  @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

When app is running notifications are not shown by default.

If you still want to present the notification then call completion handler in willPresent notification method of notification center.

Note that notification are usually used to open app. Consider displaying info from notification directly in running app.

Comment: It seems like a good idea to call completion handler, I mean leaving  messages. However, I did misunderstand the notifications showing logic, I am full with abashment now.